# Remove prefix and suffix in data without regex

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, substitution, nested-if

Goal: If cell A1 begins with "BR" replace "BR" with "-". Remove "L" suffix.
If input does not begin with "BR", Remove "L" suffix.

Constraints:
Formula can only use the following functions (no Regex):

- if
- right
- left
- mid
- or
- and
- len

Possible input value patterns/examples:

- BR3L
- BR40L
- BR500L
- BR600L
- 0L
- 5L
- 60L
- 700L
- 8000L

What I've figured out so far:
Formula that converts BR prefix values to negatives:
`if(left(a1,2)="BR","-"&right(a1,len(a1)-2),a1)`

Formula that removes "L" suffix:
`if(right(a1,1)="L",left(a1,len(a1)-1),a1)`

Comment: It is unclear why you are specifying those constraints. Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Comment: any reason why not use regex for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

overkill, but works too:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEFT(A1:A, 2)="BR", "-"&RIGHT(
 IF(RIGHT(A1:A, 1)="L", LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-1), A1:A), LEN(
 IF(RIGHT(A1:A, 1)="L", LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-1), A1:A))-2), 
 IF(RIGHT(A1:A, 1)="L", LEFT(A1:A, LEN(A1:A)-1), A1:A)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="",,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, "BR", "-"), "L", )*1))
```

[image]